# SQLite disk usage

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

SQLite has a reputation of being small, fast and flexible. I used it in one of my C++ projects to save simple statistics to a file. Once for 15 minutes 3-5 new simple records (5 rows of integers) were saved into the database. During few weeks of such SQLite usage I quickly observed clearly noticeable disk usage. I wasn't expecting that, because amount of data written was very small. If I would write it to a plain text file a reaction of the disk would be hardly noticeable. Is SQLite really such light database, or was my problem too simple for use of a relational database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VACUUM may solve your problem.
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, i have used SQLite for storing a table with the content of a English Dictionary with 100000 entries, and it occupied about 20MB, so, i don't think the problem lies on SQLite, but it would be good if you provided more clues in order to get a more accured answer

Comment: 200 bytes a word doesn't sound that compact to me!  But like you say, it's impossible to know what the OP's problem really is without more info

Comment: Index data also takes some space, moreover it can take more space than data itself.

Comment: Not, a word... A word, its meaning, and its related words

Comment: Oh right, a real dictionary!  I just assumed it was a spell-check word list - like you say, that sounds pretty good.